# How do I black list applications from the application indicator?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, steam

I am trying to black list a program from appearing in the application indicator and wondering how I can achieve this. To give my question some context, [Steam appears in my top panel](https://imgur.com/2jfDuDY) now and I wish to block it from appearing there or modify the icon.

[image: Screenshot of top panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much an answer to the question, but instead a method of removing Steam from the system tray. 
For the radiance theme that it appears you are using, open a terminal and run

```
sudo touch /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/48/steam_tray.png
```

If ambiance is being used

```
sudo touch /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/48/steam_tray.png
```

Once this is done restart steam.

This will only work if there is no steam_tray.png in the folder. If there is move the file before issuing the command.